# I want to operate Xampp and Wamp server together on my computer

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, wamp

I installed Xampp server and Wamp server together in my computer. Wampp is working fine. But Xampp is getting errors. I watched some videos on youtube. But nothing worked for me. I want to Xampp and wamp server together on my computer for 2 different projects. Is it possible? If yes, please give me a solution for it...

Comment: Why would you need that? They basically do the same job. If you need to host two projects, you can do it within one instance of either of them.

Comment: *"But Xampp is getting errors."* - And what do those errors tell you?

Comment: I am using older Wampp server version  for running old PHP version 5.5

Comment: Getting some conflicts. I think default localhost port is using Wamp server

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have 2 PHP versions available in once Apache instance, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be more specific in asking questions.

what is the error?

Maybe port conflict issue, can be fixed by changing one of those port configurations.

### Solution

**Open XAMPP > Click `config` button of MySQL module > open `my.ini` using `notepad` or any editor > Replace the number `3306` with any number you like, e.g. `3307` > Save > Close XAMPP Server completely > Open it again ( Recomanded in Administrator mode ) > start server**

Issue will be fixed.

Comment: Yes . Port Conflict issue. I dont know how to slove it

Comment: Can you show me the xampp log, please?

Comment: Yes. This is the Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/FNajfov_u4wZ

Comment: So the apache running smoothly, the problem is with MySQL. I'm adding the process of changing MySQL pot in XAMPP control panel. Wait a little bit.

Comment: ok. sure. I will wait

Comment: added the possible solution

Comment: Ok.. I will try..

Comment:  ok.......................

Comment: After try, if the solution works, please mark the answer as accepted: :)

Answer (score 0):

Use different port and drive for both Xampp and Wampp

Comment: Port Conflict issue. I dont know how to slove it